# I'm having graphic corruptions in 3D on my Intel HD 2500 (Ubuntu 20.10)

Tags: drivers, intel, 3d, visual-artifacts, intel-hd

[3D Globe on Github's Website](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IevIb.png)

[3D Scene on Babylon.js](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hxT5X.png)

This artifacting also happens in Team Fortress 2.

I have got the Intel drivers from XORG installed, as well as the mesa-vulkan-drivers.

Could it be the vulkan drivers messing with the 3D?

Answer (score 0):

I and a few other people have been getting visual artefacts with Intel HD Graphics on Ubuntu 20+. You might want to [check this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1332149/opengl-rendering-missing-some-triangles-why-and-how-to-fix) to see if you get similar symptoms and if you're using one of the kernels affected by this bug; if so, a kernel upgrade or downgrade might solve your problem -- see the answer and subsequent comment. (Of course, be careful with any kernel changes; before upgrading, be sure you know how to roll back to a previous kernel.)