# How do I fix these "diagonal tears" that appeared since I upgraded to 20.10?

Tags: graphics

Soon after I upgraded to Ubuntu 20.10, I've been experiencing these "diagonal tears" of sorts. I tried to reinstall with version 21.04, but it didn't work.

Here's what I have on my computer:

- Intel pentium
- Mesa drivers
- KDE Plasma 5 desktop

This is an example image with the highlighted text being where the effect is most visible:

[image: Screen Tearing]

Edit: I reinstalled Ubuntu 20.04, but that did not solve the issue. At this point. I'm thinking that it's an issue with drivers included with the installation or, worst-case, my graphics hardware being broken or corrupt. Hopefully, it's just the former.

Comment: Same problem here on both GNOME and KDE, I've reinstalled just about everything I can think of. Has anything worked for you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found out that this was an issue with the kernel. The issue is present from 5.8.0-49 to 5.12.5. It was fixed in 5.12.6. If you are having this issue, you should upgrade your kernel.

Comment: You are allowed to accept your own answer, if you wish.