# graphical bug that i got when i installed linux, wouldnt go away

Tags: drivers, 20.04, graphics, games, intel-graphics

I have been having this graphical bug where a lot of triangles(?) appear for some reason in 3D games, web browsers and buttons, it has been bugging me a lot and I have tried a bunch of things to get it out (screenshot from CS source, happens in other engines too)

[image]

P.S: I tried updating the drivers but I have no idea how???? (intel integrated graphics)

Comment: What is exactly the issue I should see on your screenshot?

Comment: you can see some triangles and stuff near the door, these appear alot on models in every game

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I and a few other people have been getting visual artefacts with Intel HD Graphics on Ubuntu 20+. You might want to [check this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1332149/opengl-rendering-missing-some-triangles-why-and-how-to-fix) to see if you get similar symptoms and if you're using one of the kernels affected by this bug; if so, a kernel upgrade or downgrade might solve your problem -- see the answer and subsequent comment. (Of course, be careful with any kernel changes; before upgrading, be sure you know how to roll back to a previous kernel.)